# finding max value from duplicate value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having a table structure like this:

```
Date    Count   name
2015-03-05  154903  AAA
2015-03-04  153591  AAA
2015-03-03  151277  AAA
2015-03-06  93997   BBB
2015-03-03  93294   BBB
2015-03-02  79006   BBB
2015-03-08  77324   BBB
2015-03-06  144588  AAA
2015-03-07  144119  AAA
2015-03-02  133543  AAA
2015-03-01  124435  AAA
2015-03-08  115227  AAA
2015-03-05  98866   BBB
2015-03-04  96673   BBB
2015-03-07  96298   BBB
2015-03-01  68724   BBB
2015-03-05  55748   CCC
2015-03-01  55322   CCC
```

I need to find the maximum count from every value
Eg.

```
AAA is having max value of 154903   
BBB is having max value of 98866
CCC is having max value of 55322
```

how query in mysql to fetch the data like this.

Comment: This is a smple `group by` query -- and `group by` is a very basic part of the SQL language.  My advice is to study the language a bit before attempting to use it.

Comment: What Gordon said. For Postgres start with the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to it -- just use the `max` aggregate:

```
select name, max(countfield)
from yourtable
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @GordonLinoff said, this is the very very basic of SQL.

A simple group by should do it...

`SELECT name, max(Count)
 FROM table
 GROUP BY name`

Please read some about the [Group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause.